# How do I install Ubuntu inside VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 as a testbed using virtual box . And my Host OS is also Ubuntu 12.04 . Please tell me how to install it using virtual box.

The .iso is on my desktop , suggest me how to mount this .iso using **terminal** so VirtualBox can detect this mounted .iso.

Comment: @DavidCary Yes. We should close this as a duplicate of that, then once it's closed, we should ask a moderator to merge the answers (as there are valuable answers here).