# Is it safe to install Ubuntu with a virtual drive? (With Daemon or Alcohol)

Tags: system-installation

Is it safe to install Ubuntu with a virtual diskdrive (with Daemon, Alcohol, or MagicISO)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot install Ubuntu using these softwares or vitual drives, because those will only run after Windows is loaded (more correctly, run on Windows). But, you need to run Ubuntu without loading any OS.

When you try to boot from those drives, You can't becausu  BIOS can't see those devices, simply because BIOS has no idea what softwares you installed in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

NO you cant install Ubuntu on those software.

By the way, good news is you can use VirtualBox to install Ubuntu inside Windows.

- [VirtualBox 4.2 for Windows  x86/amd64](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.0/VirtualBox-4.2.0-80737-Win.exe)

[You can refer to this tutorial for installing Ubuntu inside VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153091/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-inside-virtualbox/153098#153098)

Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: Another alternative is [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). It won't let you run Ubuntu and Windows in parallel, but it will let you install Ubuntu inside a file in your Windows partition.