# Downloading Ubuntu in Windows through Virtual Box

Tags: installation, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu inside VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153091/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-inside-virtualbox)

I am installing Ubuntu in Windows through Virtual Box. When it finishes installing it asks for restart, its restarting and then asks again for installing.

What shall I do?

Comment: Did you remove the installation medium, i.e. the CD iso from Virtual Box before restarting?

Answer (score 1):

You have 'mounted' the installation media (the ISO probably) in the virtual machine. You need to remove it from the machine by going to the settings and deselecting it. This is the equivalent of removing the CD or USB from a real computer after installation.