# install ubuntu on a virtualbox without usb or cd drive

Tags: 12.04, installation, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu inside VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153091/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-inside-virtualbox)

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 on my machine and trying to install 10.04 on virtualbox. I have already downloaded the `.iso` image. I was wondering if it's possible to install this without writing this image to usb or cd drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and start the VM, specify the iso file, and begin installation. Creating a bootable USB or CD is not necessary. Good luck.

Comment: I used to remember struggling with virtual drive softwares and guest additions for this when I was using windows. This was easy as a pie, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. You can either specify .iso file on the VM or simply use virtual drive software. This page contains valuble info:
[Feel Ubuntu on Virtual Box](http://cybrwrld.blogspot.com/2012/10/feel-ubuntu-ubuntu-on-virtual-box.html)